# What happens to male members of nurse Joy's and official Jenny's families?

Tags: pokemon

In the *Pokemon* anime, nurse Joy and official Jenny have a bunch of relatives who all have the same name and all work in Pokemon medicine/law enforcement, but only the women are in the family profession.

What happens to the boys of the Joy/Jenny family?

Comment: even some pokemon looks different but jenny and joy always look same... :D I think they focused more on pokemon than the characters :D....

Comment: One Joy had husband and daughters

Answer (score 4):

In E094 (counted by the Japanese version, which has two episodes more) we see a flashback of a young Joy and her family and it is all girls, too.

[image] [image] [image]

In DP028 we see a married Nurse Joy with two children. Her husband is an electrical engineer.

[image] [image] [image]